# I accidentally clicked deny on port open prompt

Tags: macos, terminal, firewall

I'm developing an app that binds to a local address, on a random port when it runs. I used to get a prompt to allow connections but I accidentally pressed Enter key and I think I denied the terminal app. Where should I look to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

#### System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall Options

[image]

Comment: It's not listed. I even reset the entire firewall. Nothing is listed there

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea Are you possibly referring to **Little Snitch**? https://obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html

Comment: No. I don't have it.

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea It would be helpful if you could find a screenshot on the web of what the prompt looked like.

Comment: Remember how you solved this?